How can I get the data fast from fireStore
I've a hotel booking website in which I have a /hotels-in-a-city page which is dynamic which get's list of all the hotels in a particular city through getServerSideProps() function and when I tap on a partiuclar hotel than I go to /hotels/particularhotel page which takes almost 8-10 seconds to load the data and then display it. How can I get the data from fireStore fast, I checked network tab the data is of only 20kb and it took 8.9s to come. I'm using Nextjs13 page router here. Also for cache:https://my-website.com/ shows nothing for my website that means google doesn't have any snapshot for my website, How can I fix that?
I want the pages to load fast, google should be able to crawl our website and show cache snapshot at cache:https://my-website.com
